# Calculating Income - Expenses using 3 tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a way to write a simple query and having some hard time with Left/Right JOIN functions.

Basically I want to SUM all **INCOME** which are the items that were SOLD TO CUSTOMERS
and then SUM all **EXPENSES** which are SALARY and PAYMENTS to VENDORS (to make it simple)

The product order table looks like this:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ order_number ║ product_number ║ product_quantity ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1000001      ║ 150009         ║ 50               ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1000002      ║ 150001         ║ 4100             ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1000002      ║ 150002         ║ 1200             ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1000002      ║ 150003         ║ 1350             ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1000002      ║ 150004         ║ 8200             ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
```

The product price table looks like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ product_id ║ product_name                     ║ product_price ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150001     ║ Printing Paper                   ║ 13.00         ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150002     ║ Coated Paper                     ║ 8.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150003     ║ Tissue Paper                     ║ 9.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150004     ║ Cardboard                        ║ 9.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150005     ║ Paperboard                       ║ 7.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150006     ║ Carton                           ║ 5.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150007     ║ Fineart Paper                    ║ 26.00         ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150008     ║ Pilot Pen 0.4                    ║ 5.00          ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 150009     ║ Stabilo Boss Highligher - Yellow ║ 4.50          ║
╚════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

PAYMENTS TO VENDORS are basically same as the product, just need to deduct from the results of product profit and combine it with the sum of the salary of all employees.

In total I have 2 tables as Income and 3 tables as expenses (employee, material order, material price).

The result I am aiming for at the end would be something like:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ total_profit ║
╠══════════════╣
║ 2305000      ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Product order:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Order_Details (
co_ID INT, #FK
p_ID INT, #FK
cod_quantity INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (co_ID) REFERENCES Customer_Order (co_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (p_ID) REFERENCES Product (p_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (co_ID, p_ID)
);
```

product price table:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
p_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
p_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
p_price NUMERIC(10,2) 
);
```

---

***EDIT- trying to combine between 1st and 2nd tables and deduct from the 3rd table**

```
SELECT SUM(e.e_salary)/4 AS salary_expenses
FROM Employee AS e;

SELECT SUM(vod.vod_quantity * rm.rm_price) AS total_rm_expenses
FROM Vendor_Order_Details AS vod
JOIN Raw_Material AS rm ON rm.rm_ID = vod.rm_ID;

SELECT SUM(cod.cod_quantity * p.p_price) AS total_income
FROM Customer_Order_Details AS cod
JOIN Product AS p ON p.p_ID = cod.p_ID;
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not include details about expenses, so it's not possible to compute the profit. You can, however, compute the *revenue*.

For example, you can do:

```
select sum(o.cod_quantity * p.p_price) as total_revenue
from Customer_Order_Details o
join Product p on p.p_id = o.p_id
```

**EDIT - Computing Profit**:

Since your three queries produce a single row each you can combine them using `CROSS JOIN`s. For example:

```
select
  c.total_revenue - a.salary_expenses - b.total_rm_expenses as total_profit
from (
  SELECT SUM(e.e_salary)/4 AS salary_expenses
  FROM Employee
) a
cross join (
  SELECT SUM(vod.vod_quantity * rm.rm_price) AS total_rm_expenses
  FROM Vendor_Order_Details AS vod
  JOIN Raw_Material AS rm ON rm.rm_ID = vod.rm_ID
) b
cross join (
  SELECT SUM(cod.cod_quantity * p.p_price) AS total_revenue
  FROM Customer_Order_Details AS cod
  JOIN Product AS p ON p.p_ID = cod.p_ID
) c
```

Comment: Thank you,

If I would like to deduct the expenses from this results do I need to perform another join?

the sum of material is calculated the same way as the sum of income and it should be combined with the sum of the salary of all employees

Comment: @RonSwanson Yes, you should compute the expenses on a separate query, Then you can join them and subtract them.

Comment: I edited the post with the 3 query. Should I use UNION in this case? I want to combine the two expenses and deduct from the income

Comment: @RonSwanson I added an example on how to combine all three queries as subqueries of another one.